# Multi-process Flask Application on Apache

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to create a simple web application with Python3/Flask and serve it on Apache. I could not figure out how can I make my application to respond multiple requests.

This is my wsgi file:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/FlaskDeploy')

from apps import app as application
```

This code excerpt from `httpd.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/FlaskDeploy
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/FlaskDeploy/app.wsgi
        WSGIDaemonProcess apps threads=1 python-path=/var/www/html/FlaskDeploy/env/bin:/var/www/html/FlaskDeploy/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages

        <Directory /var/www/html/FlaskDeploy>
        WSGIScriptReloading On
        WSGIProcessGroup apps
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Everything works fine but the application runs the requests one by one. For example, assume that each user performs a heavy database operation that takes 3 minutes. In this case, when 3 users from different locations open the application at the same time, the last one has to wait for 9 minutes (including the others' operations to be completed).

Basically I want to create a web application that is able to handle multiple requests.

I am coming from NodeJS world and I have never encountered with this problem on NodeJS. It runs on a single thread but can handle multiple requests.

Comment: if there is really only one process at a time handling requests, it's your apache config, not flask, that's responsible. anyway, if your requests result in operations that last more than maybe a couple hundred milliseconds, you should seriously look into a task queue, like celery

Answer (score 2):

It is only capable of only handling one request at a time, because that is what you told mod_wsgi to do in using:

```
threads=1
```

Don't set that option and it will instead default to 15 threads in the daemon process group and so that is how many requests it can handle concurrently.

If your requests are I/O bound that should be fine to begin with and you can tune things later. If your requests are more CPU bound than I/O bound, start to introduce additional processes as well and distribute requests across them.

```
processes=3 threads=5
```

Even if heavily I/O bound, do not increase threads too far per process, it is better to still spread them across processes as Python doesn't work as well with high number of threads per process.

For more information read the documentation:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/processes-and-threading.html

Comment: Thank your for help Graham but I could not understand is it solving my problem or just increase the limit from 3 users to 15? I do not understand why there is a constraint. I just want all processes to be done concurrently. On the same server (Azure), my NodeJS application is running and can respond up to 50.000 requests. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you read the documentation which was linked? WSGI applications rely on having a fixed pool of processes and threads for handling request. There is therefore a hard limit on the number of concurrent requests (not user sessions as that is different concept) the WSGI application can handle. Because daemon mode defaults to a single process and you told it the maximum number of threads that can be used in that process to handle requests is 1, you can therefore only handle on request at a time. Just remove ``threads=1`` and test again.

Comment: You are seeing NodeJS handle more concurrent requests as it uses an ASYNC model, not processes/threads and so is able to handle many more concurrent requests as there isn't a strict cap in the same way a WSGI application has when processes/threads are used to handle concurrency.

Comment: I understand. I've read the documentation and just removed the threads=1 and tested it again. Yes now the application can handle more requests but this is still a very serious problem for large number of requests like 10k, 20k. I am asking because I don't know and try to understand how can I overcome this issue or is this basically how Python web apps work? I've never encountered with this situation in PHP or Java. How great systems that use Python like Youtube or Dropbox can handle so many requests? Is WSGI too simple for this? I'd be glad if you enlighten me.

Comment: A smaller number of processes/threads doesn't mean you cannot handle a large number of users at the same time. The reason is that in a well implemented system, requests will take less than 50-100ms to process and so even with a single thread you can theoretically handle 10-20 requests per second. When you have more threads and more processes, you obviously can handle more. For 10k or 20k requests per second, you aren't going to be doing this on one host anyway, you will be running many hosts and load balancing across them. You shouldn't be thinking you can use a single host.

Comment: They recommended me to use Celery. Then what is the point to use Celery?

Comment: If your application is designed from the outset not taking into consideration how concurrency works in WSGI you will fail. If you implement things so you are dependent on having long running requests you will fail if you think you can use one host only. If you have long running requests which all they do is wait on some task to finish, you should be looking at offloading the work to backend task systems and return immediately and check results through subsequent calls.

Comment: If you have long running requests as a way of handling notifications in some way, then perhaps an ASYNC system and websockets is a better way of going about it.